# Celluloid::TaskTerminated: task was terminated

Tags: sockets, jruby, celluloid

I am using celluloid-zmq and I am connecting to multiple sockets in application. Application keeps on listening in loop in background but when I close particular socket it gives me this error "Celluloid::TaskTerminated: task was terminated "

I am ending loop on exception,

```
def puller_loop
    logger.info "polling PULL socket"
    loop {
            begin
                async.evaluate_response(pullsock.read_multipart,'PULL')
            rescue Exception => e
                break
            end
    }
end
```

Comment: Do you have code? That error is normal at disconnect, but you usually expect it. How do you close the socket?

Comment: I close socket by using close method. After closing pull socket I want app to keep listening on other sockets(DEALER in this case).

Comment: It will never reach the `rescue` because of `async`

Comment: Pardon. It will, but I'd remove `Exception` from `rescue`

Comment: Updated answer twice more.

Answer (score 1):

The listener method is crashing at socket close. You must catch & gracefully end handler loops.

Always enclose socket `read` and `write` operations in `rescue` blocks, and then `break` out of a `loop` on exception, such as the one you've mentioned, or other socket errors.

---

And since your `loop` triggers an `async` call on data arriving, the `rescue` must be in the method called by `async` ... and in `loop` itself. Make sure *not* to catch `Exception` where possible. I'm vaguely sure your error is not a subclass of `Exception`

Comment: I tried without Exception(rescue => e ). It gives same error.

Comment: Can you post the backtrace please?

Comment: Did you explicitly catch `TaskTerminated`?

Comment: No I am not explicitly catching TaskTerminated, Strange but now thing is that I am not getting exception caught in rescue when doing without Exception. Here is backtrace https://gist.github.com/pandurang90/09c5f0d29da486a8b1f4901e2b2a5426

Comment: No, it means that you closed the socket while something was reading from it or writing to it. The backtrace you sent is incomplete.

Comment: I fixed issue by creating different actor for PULL socket.